# Question about finding center of a circle touching a parabola

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

So I have a question that goes as follows:-

The circle $x^2+y^2+4\lambda x=0$ $(\lambda \in R)$ touches the parabola $y^2=8x$
. The value of $\lambda$ is given by:

The answer is $\lambda \in (0,\infty)$

But how do I visualize this? I can actually think of two cases.

Firstly, the center of the circle is $(-2\lambda,0)$, which is on the x-axis. If this touches the parabola at one point then clearly $$-2\lambda<0$$

$$\implies \lambda >0$$
This happens when the circle is touching the parabola at the vertex.

But, in my mind I can also think of the case where the centre of the circle lies on the positive x axis and touches the parabola in two points. Is this also not a probable case? If it is, what are the bound for $\lambda $ is such a case?

Comment: Actually it is possible for the center to be on the positive $x$ axis and still be tangent to the parabola at $(0,0).$ You already have an answer giving the necessary calculations to show this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, we want to solve:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x^2+y^2+4\lambda x=0
\\ y^2=8x
\end{matrix}\right.$$
We can substitute $y^2=8x$ and then we have:
$$x(x+8+4\lambda)=0$$
This has two solutions:
$$x=0\rightarrow y=0$$
Or:
$$x=-8-4\lambda \rightarrow y=\sqrt{8(-8-4\lambda)}$$
In particular, in this case, we must have:
$$-8-4\lambda>0 \leftrightarrow \lambda<-2$$
If $\lambda\geq-2$, then circle and parabola intersect at $O(0,0)$. If $\lambda<-2$, then the point of intersection is:
$$I(-8-4\lambda,\pm\sqrt{8(-8-4\lambda)})$$

Comment: Final step should be $-8-4\lambda > 0 \Rightarrow \lambda < -2$. If $\lambda \ge -2$ then the circle and the parabola intersect only at $(0,0)$, where they touch. If $\lambda < -2$ then there are two additional points of intersection at $(-8-4\lambda,\pm \sqrt{8(-8-4\lambda})$.

Comment: @gandalf61: yes, sorry. Corrected.

Comment: @Techie5879: if this answer has been useful, maybe a $+1$ or a favourite answer?

Comment: xircla, warrior mathematician

Comment: @steven gregory: haha, corrected. Sorry.

Comment: Upvoted because this shows all the necessary calculations. Still you could state more clearly that for $\lambda<-2$ there are three points of intersection, of which two are not tangent.

Comment: @Techie5879: can you favourite my answer?

Comment: @Matteo Sorry, didn't get time to check this yesterday, did it now

Comment: But this gives us the points of intersection for $\lambda$ less than 2, right? Is it not tangent for any values in that range?

Comment: @Techie5879: yes, you are right.

Comment: @Techie5879: can you favourite my answer?